# Make CSS3 spinner size match element one

Tags: css

I found code for a nice CSS3 Spinner (from link here: https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-css3-spinning-preloader/) which I implemented into my pages. I want to transform it to be able to render with relative percent height and width.

#### Demo on CodePen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBWmZY

#### My question

How to transform the spinner to make it use percents width and height instead of fixed `100px`.

The aim is to be able to make it scale to the (wrapper on my codepen) **available height**.

As you see on the demo, the div is small. The loader doesn't scale as its height and width are fixed.

I tried to simply transform as follow:

```
.loader-spinner {
    position: relative;
}
.loader {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 35px;
    min-width: 35px;
}
```

But the result not as intended. If the div is too small, I use wrapper to set a 35px minimum height but it doesn't work properly. The border radius seems not to follow and the size is quite mismatching. Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBWmKZ

I think I miss something about the wrapper or other similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you change the values to percent, then the width and height don't remain in sync.

The loader works because the height and width together form a square which is rounded off by the border-radius

Change your loader class to

```
.loader {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 100%;
        top: 100%;
        width: 14%;                // These values roughly keep your
        height: 98%;               // width and height in sync
        border-radius: 50% !important;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #3498db;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */

        &:before {
            ....
        }

        &:after {
            ....
        }
```

This will work for a 1920x1080 resolution. You will have to define different values for each resolution using media queries.